# How to add a user in database in every 5min using celery/cronjobs

Tags: python, django, celery, cron

How to add a user in database in every 5min using celery/cronjobs?

My code is not working:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab( minute='5', day_of_week="*"))
def create_user():
    try
        user = registrations.objects.get(username='username',password='password')
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = registrations(username='username', password='password')
        user.save()
```

Comment: What does _My code is not working_ mean? Could you add more information?

Comment: You want to create a new user every 5 minutes using the same username ? Username should be unique in Django. Also you shouldn't filter on password field, as it is hashed.  Plus you should specify what error you are getting.

Comment: @il_raffa i wrote this code and it is not working this is the only information that i can provide .

Comment: @sachin Gupta I am not getting any kind of error but it is not working. could you help me how can i add a user in a database in every 5 min. Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you crontab config is also wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you can do some thing like this.

```
from uuid import uuid4

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='*/5'))
def create_user():
    try:
        username = uuid4().hex # username should be unique
        user = registrations(username=username,password='pass123')
        user.save()
        # user = User.objects.create(username=username,password='pass123')  # If you are using Django auth user model, which you should. No need to call .save() on this
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)  # Log the error
```

Comment: OP wanted to create a user every 5 minutes so if it fails sometimes i guess it shouldn't be a big deal. Updated the answer to log/print the error

Comment: Your exception handler is still overbroad, and *printing* is not the way to handle what could be a critical situation. Let me put it this way: would you deploy an application with an exception handler like you have in your answer? I would not, because it guarantees that failures will be extremely difficult to detect and diagnose.